# Python Array Elements Separation

Tags: python, arrays

I have an array in **Python**  that might have two words separated by a comma ',' character in the same index for example:

```
['apple', 'banana,orange', 'strawberry']
```

My issue is: I want to divide any element(index) that contains comma ',' character into two elements. so I would like my array to be like the following:

```
['apple', 'banana', 'orange', 'strawberry']
```

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: @G.Anderson, to be honest, I do not have in my mind any idea about how it will be done

Comment: @ShadenAlsubaiheen How would you split an individual string? How would you iterate over elements of a list? How would you create a new list?

Comment: Unfortunately without at least a bit of effort, your question doesn't meet the requirement for a [mcve]. However, try looking at the `split()` method, and that may help you find some things to try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following list comprehension:
`your_list = [x.strip() for y in your_list for x in y.split(',')]`